# Negative Regexp - Exclude all php scripts but not some of them

Tags: regex, apache

As the title says, I would like to exclude from apache execution all php files but not some of them that I know to be "legal".

I've tried with `[^(file1|file2|file3|...|filen)|(\*)].[(php)|^(\*)]` but it seem to match only the last character of the file inside `()` 

I've also tried with negative lookahead but with no result.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Edit: Obviously I use `Deny from all` under that expression

Comment: you mean like this? `^(?!file1|file2|file3).*\.php$`

Comment: @DonCallisto In which directive are you using this?

Comment: In regex, `[abc]` is a character class. It matches a single character, which in this case may be `a` or `b` or `c`. Similarly, `[^abc]` matches a single character from among those not in the set. Thus `[^(foo|bar)]` matches a single character which is not `(` or `f` or `o` or `|` or ... (The repeated `o` is useless but harmless.)

Answer (score 0):

`<Files>` allows a regex use with `~` operator but `<FilesMatch>` should be preferred:

```
<FilesMatch '\.php$'>
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch '(file1|file2|file3)\.php$'>
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

[Official Doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files) says:

> Regular expressions can also be used, with the addition of the `~`
>   character. For example:
>
> `<Files ~ "\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">`
>
> `#... </Files>`
>
> would match most common Internet graphics formats. `<FilesMatch>` is
>   preferred, however.

Comment: Are you sure? Crayon Violent solution seems to work!

Comment: Regular expressions can also be used, with the addition of the ~ character.

(from [http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files))

Comment: @DonCallisto: Yes I was also reading same doc and misunderstood it initially. Corrected in the answer now.